# Fatal error: can't create .pio\build\esp32dev\.. box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, esp32, windows-11, platformio

Trying to run the Uart code on Platformio in VS code, using Windows 11. Using esp32 dev kit, when try to build the example code,running into the below issue

It's unable to create .o object file

`Fatal error: can't create .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_box\curve25519xchacha20poly1305\box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o: No such file or directory`

````
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_box\curve25519xchacha20poly1305\box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o: No such file or directory
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\consts.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\curve25519_sandy2x.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\fe51_invert.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_box\curve25519xchacha20poly1305\box_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o: No such file or directory
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\fe51_mul.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\fe51_nsquare.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_scalarmult\curve25519\sandy2x\fe51_pack.o
*** [.pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_box\curve25519xchacha20poly1305\box_seal_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o] Error 1   
*** [.pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_box\curve25519xchacha20poly1305\box_curve25519xchacha20poly1305.o] Error 1        
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create .pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_pwhash\scryptsalsa208sha256\nosse\pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_nosse.o: No such file or directory
*** [.pio\build\esp32-s3-devkitc-1\libsodium\libsodium\src\libsodium\crypto_pwhash\scryptsalsa208sha256\nosse\pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_nosse.o] Error 1 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by cloning/changing the project folder on to the drive close to the root as possible i.e. C:\examples\espidf-peripherals-uart

This looks like the limitations PATH length on Windows. More details https://github.com/esp-rs/rust/discussions/88#discussioncomment-1581167